# Can I remove dropper seatpost of the Lapierre Edge 327 plus?

Tags: saddle, seatpost, security

I recently bought a [Lapierre Edge 327 plus](https://shop.cycles-lapierre.fr/edge-327) mountain bike, that has a dropper seatpost that can be adjusted from the left handlebar.

I want to remove the seatpost when I park the bike in "unsure" places, but I am not quite sure that I can remove it.

I actually tried but at some point the seat tube is "blocked", and the adjustment works with compressed air (I guess), I am not sure I should try more to remove it.

Comment: Your translation makes sense, but the usual termn in English is "dropper seat post".  This may help you if you're looking for information in English.  [Here](https://www.lapierre-bikes.co.uk/gamme/2017/mtb/sport/edge-327)'s a link to the specs in English (that uses both "telescopic" and "dropper" to describe the seatpost)

Comment: If you're having difficulty removing the seat in the comfort of your own home, that suggests that a thief will also have difficulty, out on the street.

Comment: On the other hand, [sometimes even being inside a brick building isn't enough](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/av/uk-england-beds-bucks-herts-45213297/milton-keynes-raiders-steal-22-bikes-from-shop).

Comment: @DavidRicherby I have difficulty removing it indeed, but I feel that pulling hard would bring something out, and if the something are cables, then they could be cut ...

Comment: Parking a 1500Euro bike in "unsure places", the dropper seat post is the least of your worries. Better to buy a 15oEuro bike for those places and remove all worries of the nice bike being stolen/damaged.

Comment: @mattnz : I consider my places + their bike parking garages (equipped with cctv) as sure place. (Hypothesis.) But I don't considerer the bike parking from my workplace as sure, and it was the place I was referring to. No doubt I wouldn't park my bike on the street.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Photos on google look like internal hose routing. If the hose from the lever at the handlebar goes inside the frame, that’s going be slightly more difficult for a thief to remove the dropper post. It will also mean you can’t quicky remove the post for peace of mind.

But don’t underestimate thieves, they don’t care if they break your bike, they are normally intelligent and possibly desperate. If they cut the hose and steal your stuff, they’ll probably know someone who can buy it and fix it. So assume they’ll take it if they want it.

Better to leave your bike somewhere you feel safe.

Comment: Desperate is enough. \*pull pull yank\* Oh, a pipe broke. Well, I have most of it, I can probably sell it.

Comment: I indeed though there were cables so that I didn't pull more. Thanks.